# Subprocess Remote debugging with PyCharm 2.5

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, pycharm

I would use the remote debugging on Pycharm 2.5.
I can debug the main process but is it possible debug also the subprocess?
In the local debug there is the option "Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging". Isn't there for remote debug?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Remote Debug run configuration or remote interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

Multiprocess debug isn't supported for Remote Debug in PyCharm. I've created an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7372) for that.

But to debug multiple processes running remotely you can use [Remote Interpreters](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html). For remote run they provide the same debugging abilities as if it is local.